# Truncate call is ambigous b/w stringext.tuncate and extension.truncate

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, linq

I know there are similar questions to this but none of them have been able to help me solve this, because most of them are about float, int and doubles. Here i am trying to truncate a string from the database while also store the original value someplace else.

**Code:**

```
     objectivelist = db.GetBlogCategories(index, Size).ToList();
                if (objectivelist != null)
                {
                    categorylist.CategoryList = objectivelist;
                    objectivelist.ForEach(x => {
                        newlist.id = x.id;
                        newlist.detail = x.Detail;
                        x.Detail = x.Detail.Truncate(30);
                        categorylist.list.Add(newlist);

                    });
                    categorylist.index = index;
                    categorylist.size = Size;
                    categorylist.totalSize = db.GetBlogCategoriesCount(index, Size).Count();
                    categorylist.resultsize = db.GetBlogCategories(index, Size).Count();
                }
```

but visual studio is giving me the following error:

> Error CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'StringExt.Truncate(string, int)' and 'Extension.Truncate(string, int)'

How do i go about solving this. This shouldn't be a problem since there is no data type mismatch.

Comment: It would appear that ``Truncate()`` is not a built-in .NET method, rather you have two different static classes that define this as an extension method with the same name and the same parameter types in the same order. How is the compiler supposed to choose which of the two you want to call? You should remove one of the ``using`` statements that makes the methods accessible.

Comment: @dumetrulo - `using` directive, not `using` statement.

Comment: @dumetrulo yes thank you for the help. i did manage to solve by specifying which function i wanted to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that there are *two* extension methods it can see, and since both have identical signatures, it doesn't know which one you wanted to use.

So, unless removing a `using` directive is a possibility for taking one of the extension methods out of scope, you'll need to switch to explicit, non-extension calling of the method. E.g.

```
x.Detail = StringExt.Truncate(x.Detail,30);
```

or,

```
x.Detail = Extension.Truncate(x.Detail,30);
```